Search for column values of one sheet with row values of other sheet
I want to search for the name in A2 of sheet1 with name of A2 in Sheet2. If they are matched, then i want a condition, if the data in B2 of sheet2 matches with the data in row1 of sheet1. If the condition is true, then i want the value in C2 of sheet2 to be displayed under relevant column of sheet1.
Sheet 1 contains:
Name    Class 4 Class 5 Class 6 Class 7 Class 8 Class 9
John
Sam
Peter
Fredrick
Latam
Brendon
Sheet2 contains:
Name     Class        Rank
Brendon  Class 6    1
Fredrick Class 5    2
Sam  Class 7    3
In this case, i want the rank of Sam to get displayed under the column Class7 and row3. Similarly, rank off Brendon under class6 and row7. Please help me in this without using Vlookup function.
I used few AIs but are not showing the desired output.
